# Переключение Windows на UTC не удается

Tags: время, windows-10, xubuntu, localtime, utc

Сбивается время в windows после перезагрузки с Ubuntu.
По [этой инструкции](https://losst.ru/sbivaetsya-vremya-v-ubuntu-i-windows) пытаюсь переключить Windows на UTC. Изменение значения реестра без проблем, а вот с командой `sc config w32time start= disable` проблема. Вывод вот какой:

```
Set-Content : Не удается найти позиционный параметр, принимающий аргумент "start=".
строка:1 знак:2
+  sc config w32time start= disable
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Как исправить? Что не так делаю?

Comment: Делал по той же инструкции, у меня все сработало. Попробуй в Ubuntu поменяй, там быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Выполнить в cmd от админа, а не в powerShell

Answer (score 0):

> sc config w32time start= disable

Кажется не хватает буковки 'd' на конце:
sc config w32time start= disabled